# ¿Cómo puedo buscar una palabra y sus adyacentes en un archivo?

Tags: python-3.x, string, archivo

Estoy haciendo un buscador de documentos donde se introduce un string como parámetro y se devuelve una lista de documentos que contienen este string. La cuestión es que tiene que mostrar un pequeño extracto de cada documento donde aparezca este string con sus palabras adyacentes:

Por ejemplo para la búsqueda de "ciencia" en el documento 0001.txt:

```
1. 0001.txt
cuando la ciencia parece broma, pero no, sigue siendo ciencia Por Alvaro Manuel
```

Estoy intentando hacer la siguiente función:

```
def sacar_snippet(archivo, string_busqueda):

    snippet = []
    with open(archivo, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            words = line.split()
            for w in range(0, len(words)):
                word = preprocesar_term(words[w])
                if len(word) > 0:
                    snippet.append(word)

    for x in range(0, len(snippet)):    
        if snippet[x] == string_busqueda and string_busqueda in snippet[x]:
            print(snippet[x])
    
 
    return " ".join(snippet)
```

En snippet[x] localizo la palabra en cuestión, pero no soy capaz de continuar o si por este camino lo estoy haciendo bien. No vale que el string de búsqueda sea "casa" y detecte "fracasado", tiene que ser la palabra casa. Por otro lado, necesito obtener la posición de estas palabras ya que el documento está procesado (procesar_term, esto hace que se eliminen espacios caracteres etc.) y no vale con mostrar el documento procesado, hay que mostrar el original.

En resumen, necesito obtener la frase donde aparece el string de búsqueda. Espero que me podáis ayudar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi propuesta: leer línea por línea y usar expresiones regulares para dividirla en una lista de palabras. Si la palabra buscada esta en la lista, la condición se cumple.

Definimos una función que recibe el nombre de un archivo y la palabra a buscar. Retorna una lista, posiblemente vacía, con las lineas completas en donde se encontró la palabra.

```
import re
def buscador(palabra, archivo):
    lista = None
    patron = re.compile(r"(\w+)")
    palabra = palabra.lower()
    with open(archivo, "r") as file:
        lista = [linea.rstrip() for linea in file if palabra in patron.findall(linea.lower())]
    return lista
```

Con esto ya tienes como revisar **un** archivo y obtener todas las líneas en donde aparece la palabra.

Para buscar dentro de una lista de archivos, es cosa de aplicar la función a cada archivo de la lista.

**Demo**

Usando el texto completo del Quijote, buscare la palabra "mancha":

```
from pprint import pprint
lista = buscador("mancha", "quijote.txt")
pprint(lista)
```

produce:

```
['El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha',
 'los señores dél un libro intitulado El ingenioso hidalgo de la Mancha,',
 'Mancha, el cual os había costado mucho trabajo y era muy útil y provechoso,',
 'hidalgo de la Mancha, que desuso se hace mención, en todos estos nuestros',
 'Mancha, al abrigo del clarísimo nombre de Vuestra Excelencia, a quien, con',
 'la Mancha, hasta que el cielo depare quien le adorne de tantas cosas como',
 'Mancha, de quien hay opinión, por todos los habitadores del distrito del',
 'AL LIBRO DE DON QUIJOTE DE LA MANCHA',
 'AMADÍS DE GAULA A DON QUIJOTE DE LA MANCHA',
 'DON BELIANÍS DE GRECIA A DON QUIJOTE DE LA MANCHA',
 'ORLANDO FURIOSO A DON QUIJOTE DE LA MANCHA',
 'EL CABALLERO DEL FEBO A DON QUIJOTE DE LA MANCHA',
 'DE SOLISDÁN A DON QUIJOTE DE LA MANCHA',
 'Primera parte del ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha',
 'don Quijote de la Mancha',
 'En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho',

... etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues estabas por el camino correcto, lo único que estas complicando la cosa al separar cada letra de cada frase. Para este caso usare compresion de lista para hacer el ciclo `for` y nos ayudaremos de los metodos `find()` e `index()` para obtener los resultados esperados

```py
def sacar_snippet(archivo, string_busqueda):

    # snippet = []
    with open(archivo, "r") as f:
        lineas = f.readlines()
        lineas = [linea.replace("\n", "") for linea in lineas] #solo reemplazamos el \n que hay al final

    #guardamos solo si existe una coincidencia
    snippet = [linea for linea in lineas if linea.find(string_busqueda)!=-1]
    print(snippet)
```

Aqui lo que hemos echo es recorrer cada línea de la lista y aplicamos el método `find()` el cual regresa la posición en la que existe la coincidencia y en caso no exista devuelve `-1` por eso hacemos `if linea.find(string_busqueda)!=-1` que indica que solo guardaremos la frase si es diferente a `-1`

Bueno seguimos con el código. Ahora obtenemos el indie de donde se encuentra la palabra, esto con el método `index()`

```
    ...
    #obtenemos la posicion en la que se encuentra la palabra
    position = snippet[0].index(string_busqueda)
    print(position)
    
    #mostramos la palabra
    palabra = snippet[0][position:position+len(string_busqueda)]
    print(palabra)
    
sacar_snippet("textos.txt","ciencia")
```

Para mostrar la palabra nos ayudamos de la notación de split de una lista `[inicio:fin]` donde en inicio le pasamos la posición en que se encuentra la palabra y como fin será, la posición en que se encuentra mas el largo de la palabra.

**Resultado**

```
['cuando la ciencia parece broma, pero no, sigue siendo ciencia Por Alvaro Manuel']
10     
ciencia
```

En caso no haya coincidencias lo mas probable es que te lance un error, eso se soluciona colocando un `if snipped != []` :)

Answer (score 0):

He desarrollado un código que podrías usar para guiarte, o implementarlo directamente.

Primero que nada, podemos tomar la cadena, y dividirla en base a los espacios, de este modo separaremos las palabras, y crearemos un listado de ellas.

Segundo, creamos los métodos para buscar dicha palabra, si existe, nos encontrará su posición, calculará la siguiente y la anterior.

Tercero, una vez encontrados estos valores, revisaremos si la posición de anterior o siguiente, están disponibles para mostrarse. Es decir, si la palabra es anterior a la primera, no debería mostrar nada, y mismo caso para la palabra siguiente, que este después de la última palabra, simplemente no existen.

Cuarto, mostramos todos los resultados.

```
string = "Mi Nombre es Excorpion"
substring = "Nom"
arr = string.split()

#Buscar palabra completa en string y devolver posicion
for palabra in string.split():
  if substring == palabra:
    var = string.split().index(substring)
    print("Encontrado en posicion: " + str(var))
    ant = var - 1
    sig = var + 1
    largo = len(string.split())
    print("Largo del array " + str(largo))
    if(ant >= 0):
      print("Econtrado anterior en la pos: " + str(ant))
      print("Palabra anterior: '" + arr[ant] + "'")
    else:
      print("No hay posicion anterior")
    if(sig < largo):
      print("Econtrado siguiente en la pos: " + str(sig))
      print("Palabra siguiente: '" + arr[sig] + "'")
    else:
      print("No existe una palabra siguiente")
```